# Start jar file with TimerTask schedule in background in linux

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to run my application from a jar file in background. I've already tried nohup and & but they don't work.

```
nohup java -cp ~/DataGenerator/target/GenerateDataApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Generator.App -p ~/Text2.txt &
```

My application is a simple timer that runs every 1s, generating a random number every time and saving it to a file.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Start");
        Arguments arguments = Arguments.fromMain(args);
        SaveToFile saveToFile = new SaveToFile();
        saveToFile.creatFile(arguments.getPathToPropertiesFile());
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new SaveFileRunner(arguments), 0, 100);
        

    }
}
```

I also tried the bash script, but it didn't help either.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/DataGenerator/target
java -cp ~/DataGenerator/target/GenerateDataApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Generator.App -p ~/Text.txt
```

**Could someone advise me how can I make a timer work in the backend?**

Comment: Can you give more details about "they don't work" ? What do you expect to happen, what happens instead?

Comment: @Joni Expected: text doesn't appear and it is possible to execute another command in terminal. What happens: text appears and no further commands can be executed in the terminal.

Comment: When you say "text appears," what is this text that appears? Is it output from your program or is it something else (in which case, what is it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a program run as a background job, add `&` to the end of the command line. For example:

```
java ...parameters here... &
```

A possible problem with this is if the program writes output, that is still displayed in the terminal. You can send that output to a file.

```
java ...parameters here... >output.txt 2>&1 &
```

A second problem is that if you close the shell or logout, the program is stopped. To avoid that, use nohup.

```
nohup java ...parameters here... >output.txt 2>&1 &
```

Comment: I have already used "nohup" and "&" in command but not ">output.txt 2>&1".  I will try add it.